# How to get date & time in 13 digit(epoch time) from day,month,year,hours and minutes?

Tags: android, date, time

I am working on an application in which I have got date and time from similar dialog.
I have all this variable of type integer.
Now I have to convert this all variables in to the epoch time.
It is very important for me.
Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Calendar Class](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html), you must instantiate a new Calendar Object, set  MONTH,DAY,YEAR,HOUR,MINUTE and SECOND and then use getTime() method.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR, hours);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
    int epoch_time = (int) cal.getTimeInMillis()/1000;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Calendar:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.set(year,  month-1, date, h, min, sec);
long t = c.getTimeInMillis();
```